# clicking href on capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to tell Capybara/Cucumber to click on href  but failed trying different options. Here's the code:

```
  <div>
   <h6 class="animation-visible tile-animation link-group color-white border-round bg-primary animated" data-animation-delay="1000" data-animation="cta-1">
      <label>Option 1</label>
      <a href="http://some.com/page1/">More</a>
   </h6>
   <h6 class="animation-visible tile-animation link-group color-white border-round bg-primary animated" data-animation-delay="1000" data-animation="cta-1">
      <label>Option 2</label>
      <a href="http://some.com/page2/">More</a>
   </h6>
   ... 
</div>
```

1st attempt was to have find_link('More').click the "link".

```
within(all(.animation-visible.tile-animation.link-group.color-white.border-round.bg-primary.animated>a).[0]) do  
    find_link('More').click  
end
```

That didn't work. I've tried having it clicked straight away.

```
find(all('.animation-visible.tile-animation.link-group.color-white.border-round.bg-primary.animated>a')[0]).click
```

That didn't work either.

Just wondering if there's any other way to click Option 1? Or Option 2? These options need to be tested individually.

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: for the 1st attempt I've got this      `Unable to find link "More" (Capybara::ElementNotFound`

Comment: second way was `Unable to find link #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="a" path="/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/h6[1]/a"> (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the elements are visible on the page (not sure what the animation classes on the h6 elements are actually doing) then your first attempt wont work because of the extra > a on the selector in the within - which means you're finding the a already and then saying inside that find another a.  Your second attempt won't work because find takes a selector type and selector (selector type defaults to css) to match against elements, but all returns an array of elements (you call either find to return one element or all to return multiple elements) - the following should work instead

```
within(all('.animation-visible.tile-animation.link-group.color-white.border-round.bg-primary.animated')[0]) do  
  find_link('More').click  
end
```

which is saying inside the first .animation-visible... matching element find a link with 'More' for its text and click it.  This could also be written

```
within(first('.animation-visible.tile-animation.link-group.color-white.border-round.bg-primary.animated', minimum: 1)) do  
  click_link('More')  
end
```

That is basically the same thing except the minimum: 1 option will make it wait until at least one matching element is on the page (good for if your previous call is `#visit` or the elements are loading via ajax 
Note: you could use the minimum: 1 (or whatever number of elements you're expecting to appear on the page) on the first example too

The `find_link` calls suggested in the other answer won't work because find_link doesn't take a css selector, it takes a string to match against the text, id, or title of the link.  So the following would work

```
find_link('More', href: 'http://some.com/page1/').click
```

or

```
click_link('More', href: 'http://some.com/page1/')
```

Comment: thanks. Removing the extra >a  actually works. I need to click through all the `<h6> </h6>` tags within the CSS to perform the testing.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't these work?

First link

```
find_link("a[href$='page1/']").click
```

Second link:

```
find_link("a[href$='page2/']").click
```

> *Translation of the `css` selector:*
>   Find the link that **ends with XXX**

Comment: Try adding implicit wait after driver instantiating. Something like `driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3 `